# updateTabsetPanel to navigate between nested tabsetPanels in Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to be able to use an `actionLink` to navigate to `tabPanel`s within nested `tabsetPanel`s. I'm currently only able to navigate to the specific `tabPanel` if I already have the parent `tabPanel` selected. This nomenclature gets confusing quite quickly, so here's an example that has nested `tabPanels`, and two `actionLink`s to navigate to two of the child `tabPanel`s:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- {
    fluidPage(
        fluidRow(
            column(3,
                actionLink('subpanel_1a', 'Go to 1 A'),
                br(),
                actionLink('subpanel_1b', 'Go to 1 B')
            ),
            column(9,
                tabsetPanel(id = 'master_panel',
                    tabPanel('Primary panel 1',
                        tabsetPanel(id = 'primary_panel_1',
                            tabPanel('subpanel_1_a'),
                            tabPanel('subpanel_1_b')
                        )
                    ),
                    tabPanel('Primary panel 2',
                        tabsetPanel(id = 'primary_panel_2',
                            tabPanel('subpanel_2_a'),
                            tabPanel('subpanel_2_b')
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$subpanel_1a, {
        updateTabsetPanel(session, 'primary_panel_1', 'subpanel_1_a')
    })
    observeEvent(input$subpanel_1b, {
        updateTabsetPanel(session, 'primary_panel_1', 'subpanel_1_b')
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The `actionLink`s 'Go to 1 A' and 'Go to 1 B' only work if the currently selected parent `tabPanel` is 'Primary panel 1'---they don't work if you are in 'Primary panel 2'.

Is there a way to bypass this behaviour to have `actionLink`s that work regardless of your currently selected panel?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the same "update-logic" for your `master_panel`, before updating the subpanel.

So for 2a it would read:

```
observeEvent(input$subpanel_2a, {
    updateTabsetPanel(session, inputId = 'master_panel', selected = 'Primary panel 2')
    updateTabsetPanel(session, inputId = 'primary_panel_2', selected = 'subpanel_2_a')
  })
```

**Reproducible code:**

```
library(shiny)

ui <- {
  fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      column(3,
             actionLink('subpanel_1a', 'Go to 1 A'),
             br(),
             actionLink('subpanel_1b', 'Go to 1 B'),
             br(),
             actionLink('subpanel_2a', 'Go to 2 A'),
             br(),
             actionLink('subpanel_2b', 'Go to 2 B')
      ),
      column(9,
             tabsetPanel(id = 'master_panel',
                         tabPanel('Primary panel 1',
                                  tabsetPanel(id = 'primary_panel_1',
                                              tabPanel('subpanel_1_a'),
                                              tabPanel('subpanel_1_b')
                                  )
                         ),
                         tabPanel('Primary panel 2',
                                  tabsetPanel(id = 'primary_panel_2',
                                              tabPanel('subpanel_2_a'),
                                              tabPanel('subpanel_2_b')
                                  )
                         )
             )
      )
    )
  )
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$subpanel_1a, {
    updateTabsetPanel(session, inputId = 'master_panel', selected = 'Primary panel 1')
    updateTabsetPanel(session, inputId = 'primary_panel_1', selected = 'subpanel_1_a')
  })

  observeEvent(input$subpanel_1b, {
    updateTabsetPanel(session, inputId = 'master_panel', selected = 'Primary panel 1')
    updateTabsetPanel(session, inputId = 'primary_panel_1', selected = 'subpanel_1_b')
  })

  observeEvent(input$subpanel_2a, {
    updateTabsetPanel(session, inputId = 'master_panel', selected = 'Primary panel 2')
    updateTabsetPanel(session, inputId = 'primary_panel_2', selected = 'subpanel_2_a')
  })

  observeEvent(input$subpanel_2b, {
    updateTabsetPanel(session, inputId = 'master_panel', selected = 'Primary panel 2')
    updateTabsetPanel(session, inputId = 'primary_panel_2', selected = 'subpanel_2_b')
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Following this way you might create quite some repetitive code.

Depending on the amount of panels and subpanels you have you could try to choose names that would allow you avoid very repetitive code for this updates. So if you have `panel_1` and `panel_1_a` to `panel_5` and `panel_5_d`. You could dynamically  read the "levels" from the strings. The logic would be `panel_{FIRSTLEVELNR}_{SECONDLEVELNR}`. Then you can use sthg like:

```
library(magrittr)
levels = panel_{FIRSTLEVELNR}_{SECONDLEVELNR} >%> strsplit(split = "_") %>% unlist
updateTabsetPanel(session, inputId = 'master_panel', selected = levels[2])
updateTabsetPanel(session, inputId = 'primary_panel_1', selected = levels[3])
```

dynamically for all panel+subpanel instead of repeating that 20 times. But like i said, it depends on the amount of panel+subpanel you have and the desired naming conventions.