# Access sessions for action link in Nested Tabset and Tabpanels in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server, rshiny

Here I'm trying to create a actionlink between tabs, but I have many nested tabs within and since I'm calling the links from the nested tabs itself and not the main session, I'm not able to place the id's correctly.

I've looked into this question : [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58423549/updatetabsetpanel-to-navigate-between-nested-tabsetpanels-in-shiny-app) , but this works for only the main session.

Here's a part of my reproducible code:

```
     ui <- fluidPage(
 navbarPage(id = "Navbar",
 tabPanel("About",..
 actionLink("link_to_overview", "Let's start with the Overview!"), <--- This works
 ),
 
 tabPanel("Overview",
          tabsetPanel(id = "Tab_ov",
          tabPanel("Flights",..
          actionLink("link_to_airlines", "Let's go to the Airlines!"),<--- This doesn't work
                                    
          ),
          
          tabPanel("Airlines",..
          actionLink("link_to_domestic_stats", "Let's go to the Domestic!") <--- This doesn't work
          ),
          )),
          

    tabPanel("Statistics",
          tabsetPanel(id = "stats_tab",
          tabPanel("Domestic",..
          ),
          
          tabPanel("International",..),
          ))
          ))
          
server <-     function(input, output, session) {
observeEvent(input$link_to_overview, {
    newvalue <- "Overview"
    updateTabItems(session, "Navbar", newvalue)
  })
  
observeEvent(input$link_to_airlines, {
    updateTabsetPanel(session, inputId = 'Flights', selected = 'Tab_ov')
    updateTabsetPanel(session, inputId = 'Overview', selected = 'Airlines')
  })
  
observeEvent(input$link_to_domestic_stats, {
    updateTabsetPanel(session, inputId = 'Overview', selected = 'Statistics')
    updateTabsetPanel(session, inputId = 'stats_tab', selected = 'Domestic')
  })
  
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

```
ui <- fluidPage(navbarPage(
    id = "Navbar",
    tabPanel(
        "About",
        actionLink("link_to_overview", "Let's start with the Overview!")
    ),
    
    tabPanel("Overview",
             tabsetPanel(
                 tabPanel(
                     "Flights",
                     value = 'flights',
                     actionLink("link_to_airlines", "Let's go to the Airlines!")
                     
                     
                 ),
                 
                 tabPanel(
                     "Airlines",
                     value = 'airlines',
                     actionLink("link_to_domestic_stats", "Let's go to the Domestic!") 
                 ), id = "Tab_ov"
             ),value = 'ovview'),
    
    
    tabPanel(
        "Statistics",
        tabsetPanel(
                    tabPanel("Domestic", value = 'domestic'),
                    
                    tabPanel("International", ''),
                    id = "stats_tab")
    )
))

server <-     function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$link_to_overview, {
        
        updateTabsetPanel(session, "Navbar", 'ovview')
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$link_to_airlines, {
        updateTabsetPanel(session, inputId = 'Tab_ov', selected = 'airlines')
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$link_to_domestic_stats, {
        updateTabsetPanel(session, inputId = 'Navbar', selected = 'Statistics')
        updateTabsetPanel(session, inputId = 'stats_tab', selected = 'domestic')
    })
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thankyou! It works perfectly! You have saved me a lot of time figuring this out!